# New dependencies added to build.sbt are not seen by Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA shows its warning `Unknown artifact. Not resolved or indexed` for every new added dependency.

This error keeps happening for every new dependency added. I need to refresh cache and project as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41484503/4329372), and this might be annoying. Can anyone reproduce this or is it just me?

Comment: I'm also wandering how to disable this warning altogether

Comment: This is a bug in IntelliJ. Here the [link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203368290-New-dependencies-added-to-build-sbt-are-not-seen-by-Intellij-IDEA). You could try Alt+Enter in IntelliJ on the lines with the warning and select the "update project resolvers indexes" quickfix, then select the "local cache" index and click "update".