# Importing akka module using SBT

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, set, akka

I'm trying to import an akka dependency to my project using sbt.

The akka modules I need are `akka-actor` and `akka-remote`. The curious thing is that `akka-actor` has no problems importing, but the remote module appears as an unknown artifact.

I'm using IntelliJ and scala 2.12.1. Does someone have this problem or can help me in any way?

[image]

Comment: just ignore IntelliJ. Always trust sbt. And as far as IntelliJ is concerned... enable `auto-import` in your project.

Comment: The thing is that when I run the code, it gives an `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.actor.Scope` error, so I can't ignore it...

Answer (score 2):

Try leave a blank line between the two `libraryDependencies`:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.5.0"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-remote" % "2.5.0"
```

Or keep them in a `Seq`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.5.0",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-remote" % "2.5.0"
)
```

Comment: Does it work if you run `sbt` in command line?  If yes, the issue is `IntelliJ` specific, in which case this StackOverflow [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41372978/unknown-artifact-not-resolved-or-indexed-error-for-scalatest) might be of interest.