# Using play Json lib in spark project throws :NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt, play-json

I want to parse a json string in our spark Project. 
I use IDEA. If i run my scala code in IDEA, everything runs well. 
But When i pack a jar by IDEA+SBT and submit this jar to cluster. 
Error happpened: **Exception in thread "main" Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: play/api/libs/json/JSObject**

If i not use extra dependency jar, submit to cluster run well.

**My pack operation procedure:**

```
File -> Project Structure 
     -> Artifacts 
     -> "+" 
     -> JAR 
     -> From modules with dependencies 
     -> select "extract to the target JAR" and set "Main Class" 
     -> Bulid 
     -> Build Artifacts 
     -> Build
```

**screenshot:**

[Artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgdrZ.png)

[MANIFEST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpXX8.png)

[spark-Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46465.png)

Comment: define your dependency in sbt rather than adding it.

Comment: I add this " libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.7"  " but it still not work.

Comment: can you add this plugin: https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph 
and show the dependency tree?

Comment: I added.But can not  use because " Unknown artifact. Not resolved or index" i try to solve this by [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41372978/unknown-artifact-not-resolved-or-indexed-error-for-scalatest) but useless

Comment: Updating the project will download the plugin, the warning just means that the plugin might not have been downlaoded yet.