# intelliJ "unknown artifact. Not resolved or indexed" for scalatest with scala 2.13.1, sbt 1.3.3

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt, scalatest

The following combination in IntelliJ gives the "unknown artifact" error.

- scala 2.13.1
- Java 13 JDK
- sbt 1.3.3

The following combination don't give an error.

- scala 2.12.10
- Java 13 JDK
- sbt 1.3.3

The suggestions from an similiar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41372978/unknown-artifact-not-resolved-or-indexed-error-for-scalatest) didn't help:

- File/InvalidateAndRestart
- "update project resolvers' index"

What am I missing?

Minimal project on Github: https://github.com/hcetinkaya/sbt-scalatest-error-demo

**My system:**

**Environment (updated):**

```
OS: Windows 10.0 (Build 15063) VM on a VMWare 7.1
Scala Plugin: 2019.2.36
IntelliJ IDEA: 2019.2.3 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-192.6817.14, built on September 23, 2019 
with 
    Runtime version: 11.0.4+10-b304.69 amd64
    VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Jetbrains

JAVA_HOME: E:\apps\java\jdk-13
SBT_HOME: E:\apps\sbt\sbt-1.3.3\sbt
```

**build.sbt:**

```
scalaVersion := "2.13.1" // "2.12.10" is OK. "2.13.1" gives an "unknown artifact" error
lazy val root = project.in(file("."))
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.8" % Test
    )
)
```

**build.properties:**

```
sbt.version = 1.3.3
```

**IntelliJ project structure:**

```
Project Structure 
    Project
        Project SDK: java 13 language level: 13
    Modules
        all sources ->  language level: 13 /project default
                        dependencies Module SDK: project sdk
```

**IntelliJ settings:**

```
Build, Execution, Deployment
    Build Tools
        sbt 
            jre: E:\apps\java\jdk-13
            Launcher: E:\apps\sbt\sbt-1.3.3\bin\sbt-launch.jar
    Compiler
        Scala Compiler Server
            Use compile Server for Scala: checked
            JDK: Project default
            JVM max heap, MB: 1024
```

**UPDATE:**

sbt yields following error log:

```
error: error while loading String, class file '/modules/java.base/java/lang/String.class' is broken
(class java.lang.NullPointerException/null)
```

Details (chopped):

```
[info] Loading global plugins from C:\Users\hce\.sbt\1.0\plugins
[info] Updating ProjectRef(uri("file:/C:/Users/hce/.sbt/1.0/plugins/"), "global-plugins")...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Loading project definition from E:\learn\sbt\sbt-getting-started\project
[info] Updating ProjectRef(uri("file:/E:/learn/sbt/sbt-getting-started/project/"), "sbt-getting-started-build")...
[info] Done updating.
error: error while loading String, class file '/modules/java.base/java/lang/String.class' is broken
(class java.lang.NullPointerException/null)
[error] java.io.IOError: java.lang.RuntimeException: /packages cannot be represented as URI
[error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtPath.toUri(JrtPath.java:176)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.classpath.JrtClassPath.asURLs(DirectoryClassPath.scala:204)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.classpath.AggregateClassPath.$anonfun$asURLs$1(AggregateClassPath.scala:55)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:240)
[error]         at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:937)
[error]         at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:937)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1425)
[error]         at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:70)
...
[error] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: /packages cannot be represented as URI
[error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtPath.toUri(JrtPath.java:176)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.classpath.JrtClassPath.asURLs(DirectoryClassPath.scala:204)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.classpath.AggregateClassPath.$anonfun$asURLs$1(AggregateClassPath.scala:55)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:240)
[error]         at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:937)
[error]         at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:937)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1425)
[error]         at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:70)
[error]         at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:69)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:240)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:237)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.classpath.AggregateClassPath.asURLs(AggregateClassPath.scala:55)
...
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:111)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:130)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:111)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:37)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:119)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:20)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:56)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:18)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] java.io.IOError: java.lang.RuntimeException: /packages cannot be represented as URI
```

**UPDATE 2:**

The following combination and steps worked for me

- scala 2.13.1
- Java OpenJDK 13.0.1 (set IntelliJ sbt options to OpenJDK)
- sbt 1.3.3  (set IntelliJ sbt-launch.jar option to sbt 1.3.3 directory)

steps:

- create a new sample project in commandline (see https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/sbt-by-example.html)
- sbt compile, test should work
- import this project in IntelliJ

IntelliJ still shows the "unknown artifact" message but sbt compile, test works.

I assume, that a newly installed IntelliJ had Problems to compile the scala2_12 bridge for Cousier.

The commandline recompiled, now I can see scalatest_2.13, which was missing before, in project directory

```
null\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\scalatest\scalatest_2.13
```

[image]

Comment: I am unable to replicate the issue in IntelliJ 2019.2.3, Scala Plugin 2019.2.36.

Comment: Hi @MarioGalic: I updated my environment info. I use the same Scala Plugin version and IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition. Did you File > Invalidate Caches/Restart...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following combination and steps worked for me

```
scala 2.13.1
Java OpenJDK 13.0.1 (set IntelliJ sbt options to OpenJDK)
sbt 1.3.3 (set IntelliJ sbt-launch.jar option to sbt 1.3.3 directory)
```

steps:

```
create a new sample project in commandline (see https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/sbt-by-example.html)
sbt compile, test should work
import this project in IntelliJ
```

IntelliJ still shows the "unknown artifact" message but sbt compile, test works.